# Getting clientX with jQuery Tooltip plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tooltip

I'm using this [tooltip plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip):

I'm trying to get the clientX of the tooltip area. Meaning, the X position where the client hovered over the element. So far, no luck.

Here's an example:

```
$(this).find("div.GanttRange[data-RangeID != '']").tooltip({
    bodyHandler: function (e) {
        if (!_self.DragInProgress) {
            result = window[_self.ElementRangeTooltipFunction](_self.GetRelativeClientX(e.clientX));
        } else {
            result = "";
        }
        return result;
    },
    opacity: 0,
    track: true,
    showURL: false
});
```

`e` is undefined in this context. How do I find it otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039146/mouseover-function-losing-scope-when-called-from-anonymous-function) I've solved this issue by modifying the Tooltip plugin code.

In the `tooltip` anonymous function, replace this:

```
.mouseover(save)
```

with this:

```
.mouseover(function(evt){save.call(this, evt)})
```

In the `Save` function, replace this:

```
function save() {
```

with this:

```
function save(evt) {
```

and this:

```
var bodyContent = settings(this).bodyHandler.call(this);
```

with this:

```
var bodyContent = settings(this).bodyHandler.call(this, evt.clientX);
```