# mouseover function losing scope when called from anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tooltip

I'm looking into the code of the jQuery ToolTip plugin(hereinafter Tooltip), and have a noticed a behaviour I don't fully understand.

Tooltip binds a mouseover function like so:

```
.mouseover(save)
```

When called in this way, `this` variable is `HtmlDivElement`.

I tried changing the `mouseover` to this:

```
.mouseover(function(e){save(event)})
```

Since I'm looking for the MouseEvent. However, now `this` variable is `Window`.

I found a way to baypass this and get the `HtmlDivElement` by using this line of code:

```
.mouseover(function(e){save(this, event)})
```

and using `this` as a replacment for the `this` inside the function.

My question is - why is the `save` function losing it's scope when being called inside an anonymous function inside the mouseover binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `this` is established upon each function call. When your anonymous function calls that "save" function, it's not doing anything to establish what `this` should be, so it's the default value: the global object ("window").

You can do this:

```
.mouseover(function(e){ save.call(this, e); })
```

to make `this` take on the value you need. The `this` value in the handler will be arranged by the framework, so by using `.call()` you're passing it on to the "save" function.

To repeat: in JavaScript, `this` is not determined by static structure of the code. Instead, it depends on the situation of each individual function call. That means that for any function, no matter how it's declared, the value of `this` may be a complete surprise on any given function call.

Comment: Thanks, This really helped me understand the `.call()` I've seen everywhere a bit better.